# Cron jobs are not working

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, cron

I was created the `Cron` jobs it is showing on `admin panel` and I have set the time also, but it is not running.

**my code is**

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <tabs>
        <Auto translate="label">
            <label>Auto Replenish</label>
            <sort_order>120</sort_order>
        </Auto>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <autoreplenish translate="label" module="autoreplenish">
            <label>Auto Replenish Settings</label>
            <tab>Auto</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general_settings translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Auto Replenish</label>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enable_disable translate="label, comment">
                            <label>Enable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </enable_disable>
                    </fields>
                </general_settings>
            </groups>
        </autoreplenish>
        <catalog>
            <groups>
                <configurable_cron translate="label">
                    <label>Cron Schedule</label>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <time translate="label">
                            <label>Start Time</label>
                            <frontend_type>time</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </time>
                        <frequency translate="label">
                            <label>Frequency</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_cron_frequency</source_model>
                            <backend_model>autoreplenish/adminhtml_system_config_backend_autoreplenish_cron</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </frequency>
                    </fields>
                </configurable_cron>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**cron.php**

```
<?php

class Easylife_Autoreplenish_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Backend_Autoreplenish_Cron extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    const CRON_STRING_PATH = 'crontab/jobs/my_cron/schedule/cron_expr';
    protected function _afterSave()
    {
        $time = $this->getData('groups/configurable_cron/fields/time/value');
        $frequencyDaily = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_DAILY;
        $frequencyWeekly = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_WEEKLY;
        $frequencyMonthly = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_MONTHLY;
        $cronDayOfWeek = date('N');
        Mage::log(date('N'));
        $cronExprArray = array(
            intval($time[1]),                                   # Minute
            intval($time[0]),                                   # Hour
            (frequency == $frequencyMonthly) ? '1' : '*',       # Day of the Month
            '*',                                                # Month of the Year
            (frequency == $frequencyWeekly) ? '1' : '*',        # Day of the Week
        );
        $cronExprString = join(' ', $cronExprArray);
        Mage::log($cronExprArray);
        try {
            Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
                ->load(self::CRON_STRING_PATH, 'path')
                ->setValue($cronExprString)
                ->setPath(self::CRON_STRING_PATH)
                ->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception(Mage::helper('cron')->__('Unable to save the cron expression.'));
        }
    }
}
```

**Replenish.php**

```
<?php


class Easylife_Autoreplenish_Model_Replenish
{
    public function run()
    {
        Mage::log("Cron Jobs");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<crontab>

        <jobs>
            <my_cron>
                <run>
                    <model>autoreplenish/replenish::run</model>
                </run>
            </my_cron>

        </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

I am save the CST time @ 11:38:00 and it's saved on `core_config_data` as `catalog/configurable_cron/time = 11,38,00` & `catalog/configurable_cron/frequency = D` & `crontab/jobs/my_cron/schedule/cron_expr = 38 11 * * *`. But it's not saved on `cron_schedule`.

Can you tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume it is because there is no `cron_expr` in your config.xml and when cron.php is run there is no store so there is no core_config_data, maybe have a look at `Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::setCronExpr`

Comment: @DavidManners, Yes I don't have `cron_expr` in my `config.xml` Because I have stored in `core_config_data`.

Comment: do you call the cron.sh via linux cron regularly?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt, No, I'm using windows. Can you tell me how can call `cron.sh` via windows.

Comment: Manoj I have no idea. But without external call to the magento cron there will no cronjob run. What you can do is just call `php cron.php`

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you run Magento's cron.php (located in Magento root folder) every 5 minutes or so (in your server's crontab). Doing so, Magento will check all the XML files for your modules and check for the  nodes. Then it will add jobs to the queue in table `cron_schedule` (in your DB). After a short moment, you shoudl see this table populating. Magento will launch the crons by itself.

Hope this helped.

Comment: how can i run `cron.php'? can u suggest me.

Comment: in your server's /etc/crontab add the line suggested by @sebastian `*/5 * * * * php -f /path/to/magento/cron.php`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Julien you have to run cron.php in root directory.
With

`crontab -e`

in terminal you can add the cronjob to the server.
This is the entry you have to make:

`*/5 * * * * php -f /path/to/magento/cron.php`

To list all cronjobs you can use

`crontab -l`

I read to late that your magento is running on **windows**. On windows you use the [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler) to run cron.php

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend AOE Scheduler extension to see what's going on with cron. Among other things it shows if Magento has "heartbeat". If not, then it probably means that there's something amiss with crontab: either it doesn't run cron.php, insufficent permissions, you try to run it directly without interpreter or your path is wrong.

You can find the extension here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html